# Store data for multiple users in one place

Tags: c#, data-storage

I have a C# application which is used to modify PowerPoint files. The files are in our network and a lot of people need to work with them. But at every given time, only one person works with a presentation.
I used to store some metadata, for each presentation, in a central serialized xml file located in our network. The struture of the metadata is a simple List where each item is a filename and other properties. The filename is used to identify each entry.

Now my program is used often used by different people, who are working on different presentations and when they go home, my program saves the metadata to the file. Unfortunately, the last user to go home wins and overwrites all changes by other users.

So how can I avoid that? Clearly, I need a better data storage technique, which saves only the changes made by the user. But I cannot use any other technique than files stored on our network (but I am not limited to xml files...)

Comment: Isn't the answer super basic? Use a better technique.
Store multiple files, or use subelements in the XML structure, on for each user.
I'm failing to understand the question

Comment: What do you expect your program to do?

Comment: @Oxinabox I cannot store the data for each user, because the data are not user-related, they are related to each Presentation. 
I would like to avoid multiple files, I would end up with a folder with 5000 files within a year.

Comment: Well then store the data for presentation. same principle applies. 
5000 files/year isn't too bad. I think a database probably is the way to go though.

Comment: Oxinabox , currently that happens - but if the file contains a newer version for pres1 while I save pres2, all changes to pres1 are lost.
I could deserialize the file from disk and compare the content, but since the saves a tightly spaced (17.00 when the majority goes home) this is not foolprof and might generate "file in use" errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) database? It stores all it's data in a single file (which you can store on your network), and gives you the flexibility of a relational database where you can use techniques like pessimistic and/or optimistic concurrency checks. You'll also be able to more easily store each user's data.

**EDIT:** [An SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591002/how-can-i-use-sqlite-in-a-c-sharp-project) which deals with how to use SQLite from c# applications

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good idea! I ruled out a database because our server is managed by another firm.